# Jetpack Compose (1.1.1): Recompose Does not happen when a Boolean value changes in LaunchedEffect

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to implement a screen with some animation and transition with MotionLayout & AnimatedVisiblity.

In LaunchedEffect, I have an if statement to check if a float value is less than 1, then increment it by 0.05f for every 10 milliseconds. When the value >= 1f, then showSummary (Boolean) toggles to true. The issue is that the content does not appear when showSummary is true.

When I add Text(text = animationProgress.toString()) and Text(text = showSummary.toString()) the value changes do get displayed in the screen.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMotionApi::class)
@Composable
fun SomeView() {
    var showSummary by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var animationProgress by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = animationProgress, key2 = showSummary) {
        if (animationProgress < 1f) {
            delay(10L)
            animationProgress += 0.05f
        }

        if (animationProgress >= 1f)
            showSummary = true
    }

    MotionLayout(
        start = ConstraintSet("""{
                checkmark: {
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    start: ['outerParent', 'start', 0],
                    end: ['outerParent', 'end', 0],
                    top: ['outerParent', 'top', 0],
                    bottom: ['outerParent', 'bottom', 0]
                }
            }""".trimMargin()),
        end = ConstraintSet("""{
                checkmark: {
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    top: ['outerParent', 'top', 0],
                    start: ['outerParent', 'start', 0],
                    end: ['outerParent', 'end', 0],
                },
                body: {
                    width: 'spread',
                    top: ['checkmark', 'bottom', 16],
                    start: ['outerParent', 'start', 0],
                    end: ['outerParent', 'end', 0]
                }
            }""".trimMargin()
        ), progress = animationProgress
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(bottom = 40.dp)
                .layoutId("outerParent")
        ) {
            Checkmark()
            AnimatedVisibility (
                visible = showSummary,
                enter = fadeIn(),
                exit = fadeOut(),
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            ) {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .layoutId("body")
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Header")
                    Text(text ="Content")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get AnimatedVisibility after removing it from MotionLayout scope.

Comment: You can control the visibility in the constraint set with 
{visibility: 'gone' or 'visible' or 'invisible'}